# Pivoting ag-grid angular table

Tags: css, angular, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using angular ag-grid to add a table to a web-app.
After some struggle I am finally able to display it and it looks like this:

| Maturity | price | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/10/2019 | 500 | 5.2 |
| 11/10/2019 | 550 | 7.2 |
| 11/10/2019 | 600 | 8.4 |
| 15/11/2019 | 520 | 3.6 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My goal is to flip it to look like that:

| - | 500 | 520 | 550 | 600 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/10/2019 | 5.2 | - | 7.2 | 8.4 | ... |
| 15/11/2019 | - | 3.6 | - | - | ... |

I have played around with the "pivoMode" functionality without great success.
Here is the code I am using to produce the first table:

```
@component({
 selector: 'app-volume-grid',
 templateUrl: 'app-volume-grid.co;ponent.html',
 styleUtls: ['app-volume-grid.co;ponent.scss'],
 ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Volume {
 @input() data:any [] = [];
 
 public gridOptions:GridOptions = {
 ...commonFridOptions,
 columnDefs: [
  {headerName: 'Maturity'; field: 'Maturity'; colId:'Maturity', width: 100 },
  {headerName: 'price'; field: 'price'; colId:'price', width: 100 },
  {headerName: 'volume'; field: 'volume'; colId:'volume', width: 100 },
 ],
 defaultColDef: {
  ...commonGridOptions.defeultColDef,
  suppressMenu: true,
 }
}
```

Any idea how I could use pivotmode or else to achieve this?

This is my first attempt at angular and front end in general so let me know if I am missing anything in the explanation.

Sample data:

```
{{"Maturity" : "11/10/2019", "price" : "500", "volume" : "5.2"},{"Maturity" : "11/10/2019", "price" : "550", "volume" : "7.2"},  ...}
```

Comment: can you add some sample data here?

Comment: Sure ! Editing the post to add some sample data.